# Does anybody know Context-Environment (CE) Machine (interpreter)?

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming, semantics

I am currently studying the small-step semantics using Context- Environment machine for lambda calculus.

In this kind of machine, or say interpreter, the definition of the closure is  open lambda terms paired with an environment component that defines the meaning of free variables in the closure.

When defining the environment component, the literature says:

```
ρ ∈ Env = Var ⇀ Clo.
```

which is to map an variable to a closure.

My question is: 
 Why closure?  It is not straightforward to understand.

For example, you can imagine: 
 According to the definition of closure, every expression has its environment, and thus a closure, then if the current expression to evaluate is a variable v, then we can reference to its environment for v, which will return a closure? What's that? If the variable's value is 5, why not just give me 5, rather than a *closure*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those examples are often defined in the context of λ-calculus without
constants :

```
terms ::=
        | x       variable
        | t₁ t₂   application
        | λx.t    abstraction
```

In this case, only abstractions are values : the only *values* (normal
forms of a closed terms) are of the form `λx.t`; indeed, `x` is not
a closed term and `t₁ t₂` can be further reduced.

When using an `(t,ρ)` term-environment pair (the idea is that `ρ`
keeps definitions for free variables of `t`, instead of substituting
them away which is a costly operation), the values in ρ may have free
variables themselves, and therefore need to carry their own
environment : environment should be `Var → (Value * Env)`. As in this
restricted example, the only possible values are abstractions, we name
a pair of a lambda and its environment a "closure", hence `Var → Clo`.

Now you may want to add other things to your language, such as
constants (`5`, `true`, etc.), pairs, let-definitions, continuations,
etc. The definition of terms will be extended in each case, and the
definition of values may also change, for example `2 + 3` won't be
a value but `5` will. Value may or may not capture variables from the
environment : `(λf.f x)` does, but `5` doesn't. However, we keep the
uniform definition of `Env := Var → (Value * Env)`, so that we don't
have to distinguish between those.

You don't actually need the captured environment to be *exactly* the
same as the environment you had at the time of the value
construction. You only need to keep bindings for the value that are
actually captured in the value, such as `x` in `(λf. f x)` (this is
called "weakening"). In particular, you can always express the
"closure" for `5` as `(5, ∅)`.